# How to submit a support case?

Tags: support, help

It appears the SalesForce website does not work!  If I go here (I have tried this in multiple browsers) https://help.salesforce.com/ and click Contact Support -> Open a Case, it redirects me to https://help.salesforce.com/hthome?err=1.  It does this whether I am logged in or not.

This has been well documented, but apparently never fixed:

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h3S5AAI

I am really surprised something so simple has slipped through the cracks.

How can I submit a support case?

Comment: The portal is opening fine for me to contact support. you can call them at their direct lines at 1800nosoftware and open a case based on what support your company enrolled for, Premier (or) Basic

Comment: Well I am not sure why myself and the several other people on that post I linked to above aren't able to do so.  I only have a developer account, maybe that's why.

Comment: Yep I am unable to open a case from developer account too.  Call them to get the case opened.

Comment: Yeah the issue is it is a dev account. What is the issue you are trying to create a case for? Maybe it's something that can be answered by the dev community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might need to read the User Agreement for Developer Acccounts. I don't know what it says myself because we are also a customer, but given that these accounts are free it's very likely support is not included. The submission of a case online has been fine for many years, I'm sure its related to the Developer account User Agreement.

It would not be unprecendented for this to be the case. I remember having trouble finding out how to reach Google support before we were a paying company.